# Como criar uma tabela dinâmica com vários campos de linha usando o VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu quero criar uma tabela dinâmica com vários campos de linha. Mas, esses campos de linha precisam ser alterados de acordo com os dados digitados na planilha do Excel.

Tentei definir as variáveis e usar comandos "With" e "for", como no código a seguir.

```vb
Option Explicit 
Private Sub PivotTable()

        Dim Wsheet      As Worksheet, Wsheet2   As Worksheet
        Dim File        As Workbook
        Dim PvtCache    As PivotCache
        Dim Pvtbl       As PivotTable
        Dim RLast       As Double
        Dim i           As Variant, X            As Variant

        Set File = ThisWorkbook
        Set Wsheet = Sheets("Data")
        'Create sheet for pivot table 
        Set Wsheet2 = Sheets.Add(After:=Wsheet)
        Wsheet2.Name = "PivotTable"     

        Set PvtCache = File.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatWsheetse, SourceData:=Wsheet.Range("A1:D45"))
        Set Pvtbl = Wsheet2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Wsheet2.Range("A3"), TableName:="Manual_Bordo")

            With Pvtbl
            'setting rows fields
            Set Wsheet = Sheets("Data")
            RLast = Wsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'digitar os campos na coluna "F".
            For i = 1 To RLast
                Set X = Wsheet.Range("F" & i)
                With .PivotFields(X)             'o erro ocorre nesse comando
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = i
                End With

            Next
            'setting pivot Data
                With .PivotFields("Size")
                    .Orientation = xlDataField
                    .Position = i
                    .Function = xlSum
                    .NumberFormat = "#.##0,0"
                    .Name = "Size"
                End With
            Next            
        End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

A variável "X" armazena o nome correto do campo, mas o comando depura com o erro 1004: não é possível obter a propriedade PivotFields da classe de PivotTable.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri como resolver:
A variável X dever ser definida como String

```vb
Dim X as String

X = Wsheet.Range("F" & i)
```

Além disso, havia um erro no comando `for` pois `i` deve iniciar com 1